# how to get partial string using matches() in android

Tags: android, string, search

I am developing search engine.

I want to get some part of string using matches() function.

For example,

my keyword is 'specific' and string is like below.

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the **specific** language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.

You can see that specific word is in the middle and I want to get 10 words of forward and backward words with 'specific' as the center...

So the I want the result,

See the License for the **specific** language governing permissions

How can I do this?

Comment: How large is the text you want to search through? Do you have limitations on how much extra space you need? Do you have limitations on how quickly the code should get you the result?

Answer (score 0):

1. split the string into a char[] by ' '(space)
2. iterate the array to match the key word
3. when found, get the index
4. get what you need by the index

you can make the 1 step by String method like str.toCharArray(..)

Comment: Very easy and simple way! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two ways come to my mind.

1. Search for "specific", get it's index, search both backwards and forward for " " or puntuation characters.
2. Get used to regex. For example, you could use this one to match `specific language governing permissions and`:

   `[](?<! ).+[ ]specific[ ](?! ).+[ ](?! ).+[ ](?! ).+[ ](?! ).+[ ] -U`

Probably the first option will be much more simple to create,mantain, debug, and execute. Regex is great for its flexibility, but doing simple operations as `String.indexOf()` will most surely be faster.

If it were for a university homework, I would do both. For the real world, I would keep it simple and efficient with indexOf() operations.

pd: `-U` is a regex modifier. Most of Android's regex-related function support modifiers.

Comment: Thank you for sincere answer! I am actually doing internship project.
I will try first way!